# Which data structure should I use for having sorted data, where the key can be used on multiple entries

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have some set of data to store where I have a key to find the object related, but the key is not unique and the same key can have multiple pointers.

I would like to be able to throw this data into a structure a bit like the SortedList, but it require unique keys to work.

Is there any out of the box C# object that will allow me to do this. In following example I am using a string as reference object, but it might as well be any other object, just like a SortedList can contain any type of object.

eg.

```
unknownDatastructure structure = new unknownDatastructure<string, string>();
structure.add("left","the remainder after a removal");
structure.add("left","a direction opposite of right");
structure.add("right","a direction opposite of left");
structure.add("right","opposite of being wrong");
```

and I would like to either get an array of objects back that matches the search key when called, or first entry (and I can find remaining via the index).

eg.

```
List<string> results = structure.FindAll("Left");
```

Where the List would contain the actual referenced object, in this case "the remainder of a removal" and "a direction opposite of right".

```
int firstmatch = structure.FindIndex("Right");
```

Where the int would be 2 (0 = first left, 1 = second left, 2 = first right, 3 = second right). I do not care which order the 2 lefts or the 2 rights are sorted, just need to be able to locate the entry of the first repeat, then I can step forward through all entries as required to create the "FindAll" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<K,V>` does not support duplicate keys. You will have to maintain a list of all entries for each key:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me ... 1 entry, have the entry be a list of all matches., then figure out which structure to store those lists by. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own:

```
Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> dictionary;
```

Then your code would look a little like:

```
List<TValue> list;
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
{
  list = new List<TValue>();
  dictionary[key] = list;
}

list.Add("whatever...");
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand this code. Bookmarked your reply to read up on the unknown functions for later. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No worries... the idea is, `TryGetValue()` will return `true` only if it already has the key.  Otherwise it will return `false`.  This allows you to create a new `List<>` only when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Is there any reason you don't want to create a class or struct to contain your data? It would allow you to easily add functionality later on.

Adding either of the above to a `List<T>` will let you find the element by using a predicate. `myList.FindAll(x => x.MyKey == "left");`

Comment: I already have a class for the object (the 2nd value) I need to refer to, and hoped to find a good storage structure for these within the standard classes. I will be using a List<class> to store similar objects and for now use the SortedList to store those lists. :)

Comment: @Taoh I guess I missed the point of you needing a Dictionary then. Not saying you don't need it, but it seems like you could do everything you need in your examples by just sticking with a single List. LINQ and predicates allow for all sorts of searching on your collection.

Comment: I think I were just being unclear in my question. I have a bunch of objects, these have 1 reference name, but multiple objects can have the same reference name. I need to be able to quickly (not traverse all objects) find all objects with reference name X. I do not know how to use Dictionary, so I will need to read up on it. Worst case I learn something new :)